# Rhino Mocks for Silverlight is missing

Tags: silverlight, mocking, rhino-mocks, rhino

I can't find Rhino Mocks executables for Silverlight.

I've googled a lot. It should be here http://ayende.com/blog/3843/rhino-mocks-3-5-silverlight. But link does't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think the latest repository is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks).

Answer (score 0):

The link is broken for quite a while now (at least half year, might be more). Myself, I have never seen actual RhinoMocks executables for Silverlight (been looking for them too!). Since you got the same problem, perhaps it will be a good idea to try out one of the new mocking frameworks which **both support Silverlight** and are constantly gaining on popularity:

- [FakeItEasy](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy/)
- [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

If you have some RhinoMocks background, using either of them will be easy and intuitive.